# Why do I get 405 error after adding a rewrite rule?

Tags: iis, iis-6

I need the rewrite rule for being able to refresh a webpage (based on AngularJS), without getting 404 error - and this is working perfect. However this is causing 405 error for any method except GET (deploy to local IIS).

** WebDAV is not enabled **

Below is the rule which I am adding to the web.config file:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Redirect to index.html" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*[^/])$" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Comment: I think that's because index.html don't allow POST by default. You could confirm this by  disable rule and access /index.html. I believe you will receive same error. And if you enable failed request tracing, you should get Incorrect function.
 (0x80070001). Its pure angular side issue.

Comment: @JokiesDing Thanks for explanation. What do you suggest me to do?

Comment: @amir.algazi I think I know where is the problem. Staticfile handler block post request to static content. So it is unavailable to handle post request with static file handler. To fix this, you have to use other handler to handle the request.http://sysadmin.circularvale.com/server-config/enabling-post-requests-to-static-eg-html-pages-using-iis-7/.